# how to determine which textbox is focused and add text to it...........?

Tags: c#, winforms

im doing  a complex calculator in  C#.  the first textbox accepts the real part and the second accepts the immaginary part. i wanna be able to use the mouse to enter values also. so if i click button1 it will concat "1" to the value in the textbox on which the focus is on . i cant determine  which textbox is focused. i tried the  stuff some  people posted, like using GotFocus for exemple, and non had worked..

```
    private Control focusedControl;

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        focusedControl = (Control)sender;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (focusedControl != null)
        {
            focusedControl.Focus();
            SendKeys.Send("1"); 

        }

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1804596/961113

Answer (score 7):

```
        if ((txtBox as Control).Focused)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add more detail and explanation to your answer.

Comment: It is an if statement.

Answer (score 6):

```
private TextBox focusedControl;

private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    focusedControl = (TextBox)sender;
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (focusedControl != null)
    {   

        focusedControl.Text  += "1";
    }

}
```

You just have to use TextBox_GotFocus as the EventHandler for both textboxes.

Comment: I guess you need to cast `sender` to `TextBox`, not `Control`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 
    private TextBox focusedTextbox = null; 

    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) 
        { 
            tb.Enter += textBox_Enter; 
        } 
    } 

    void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        focusedTextbox = (TextBox)sender; 
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (focusedTextbox != null) 
        { 
            // put something in textbox 

        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found this code on the internet, tell me what you think :)

```
    private TextBox findFocused(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control ctl in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl.HasChildren == true)
                return findFocused(ctl);
            else if (ctl is TextBox && ctl.Focused)
                return ctl as TextBox;
        }

        return null;
    }
// usage: if starting with the form  
TextBox txt = findFocused(this);
```

Good luck!